# WPF animation position depending on window size

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to create an animation (from xaml if possible) in which a Rectangle object slides from outside the page (on its right) and fits in it snuggly.

The animation should work on windows of any size, and for this reason I create the it like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SlidingIntro">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="icon">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AnimationCanvas}"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
<Page.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlidingIntro}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Page.Triggers>
```

With the Rectangle initialized like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="AnimationCanvas">
        <Rectangle Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AnimationCanvas}" 
                       Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=AnimationCanvas}" 
                       Canvas.Top="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=AnimationCanvas, Converter={StaticResource Math}, ConverterParameter=-x/2}"
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AnimationCanvas}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
```

The thing is the rectangle appears on its final position without it being animated. Its like the first frame's value is 0 because the binding fails... Something about it being Frozen?

Comment: Where do you apply the animation?

Comment: The animation starts inmediately after load. I know the animation itself works because I can set the first frame's value to the window with manually, so the problem must have something to do with the binding.

Comment: if you're going to reuse this animation on different rectangles, I would go for a blend behavior, but that is defined in C# code, not XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.X"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Rectangle}}"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The actual solution to my problem came by using DoubleAnimations instead of KeyFrames. If you changed that in my original code it would work too.